# Hibernate tutorial not working

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have been following the hibernate tutorial on http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

and as others have pointed out in various web boards, it's incomplete.
When I run this command:

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager" -Dexec.args="store"

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building First Hibernate Tutorial 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hibernate-tutorial >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hibernate-tutorial <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ hibernate-tutorial ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.962s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 30 17:03:34 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (d
efault-cli) on project hibernate-tutorial: An exception occured while executing
the Java class. org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

So I think the problem is obvious. When maven executes java, java doesn't know where to find my 'EventManager'. I tried the following on my command line:

> set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\robe\Documents\hibernate\project1\src\main\java\org

What else could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your classpath is wrong. Try

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\robe\Documents\hibernate\project1\src\main\java
```

You don't need the org. That is part of the full qualified class name. The full class name is org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager

I am not familiar with this tutorial's problem. You may get other classpath errors. If you do you can add more to the class path by separating them by a semi colon.

Also you are setting the classpath in the cmd line. It will only be set for that session so you will have to run your mavem command in the same one. Or set it in your global environment variables

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I still get the same error. My EventManager.java is under C:\Users\robe\Documents\hibernate\project1\src\main\java\org\hibernate\tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
mvn clean install
```

I know it sounds obvious, but when I tried to execute

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager" -Dexec.args="store"
```

I get the same error as you did. But after running mvn clean install the app started (I ran clean install for this code https://github.com/stivlo/hibernate-tutorial, it looks it is the same thing)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but now i get this error when running mvn clean install: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
:clean (default-clean) on project hibernate-tutorial: Failed to clean project: F
ailed to delete C:\Users\robe\Documents\hibernate\project1\src\main\java\target\
data\tutorial.log -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]

Comment: It looks like your "tutorial.log" file is locked, and can't be deleted. Try deleting the whole "target" folder before running mvn clean install. If you still have problems, let me know.